# Rails Generate Model not using inflection rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to generate a 'Status' model in Rails 5.1 and when I run

```
rails generate model status
```

I get

```
The model name 's' was recognized as a plural, using the singular '' instead. Override with --force-plural or setup custom inflection rules for this noun before running the generator.
```

I then added a new rule in config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'status', 'statuses'
end
```

ran the command again and I still get the error.

What am I missing?

Comment: That `generate` line works, no need for any inflections, there is something else causing this error.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can Change name to be state,  so the plural  is states